# Could not download auto-value.jar (com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5.2): No cached version available for offline mode

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, build.gradle, auto-value

I have almost tried everything I know, but still as soon as I update my Android studio to the latest version it shows this error.What should I do?

The gradle.build is:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven{
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem today. I solved it by downloading the auto-value.jar file manually. Then I added the jar file to the libs folder. After doing so I synced the gradle files.

Here are details on how to add a jar file into Android Studio.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16628496/8065933

All the best.

Comment: thanks,it was a great help.It actually worked for me

Comment: @PriyaPal Good. You can upvote the answer or mark it as the correct answer if it worked for you.